# what sort of app is this - upload an image on to an existing one for previewing

Tags: flash

quite a vague question

i'm looking to develop an application that essentially allows the user to upload their company logo and have it appear on an image to simulate what a product might look like with their branding on if that makes sense

does this kind of app have a proper name or search term i could work from?

ideally there'd be a prebuilt solution as my flash isn't very good..i have an idea to achieve this with say PHP and a combination of jquery and css but i think a flash solution would be more elegant

thanks for any pointers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're interested in using PHP, the easiest solution would probably be to use the [GD library](http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php) to merge the two images (the logo and your image) together. You can then output the result as a single image to the user without the need for any flash or css.

Take a look at the [imagecopyresized](http://us.php.net/imagecopyresized) and [imagecopymerged](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopymerge.php) functions which will allow you to resize any logo they upload and merge it with your image.

Comment: thanks, i'll take a look. that was more or less my thinking. I'll at least be able to develop this in PHP. flash solution would probably be more suitable but as stated i'm inept with the technology